# Searching dependency for android Gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I'm looking for an android gradle dependencies.

The website http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ seems to stop working.

Any similar sites ?

Otherwise, Tips to searching specifics library ?

Answer (score 1):

https://mvnrepository.com/ - top 1 for dependencies search.

Comment: prefer a website like the reference below http://gradleplease.appspot.com/